# Printing list side by side

Tags: python, list

How can I print two lists as follows:

```
A=[1,2,3,4,5]
B=[6,7,8]
```

Output should be

**1.)**

A : [1,2,3,4,5]

B : [6,7,8]

**2.)**

[1,2,3,4,5] [6,7,8]

Comment: which one is expected output? 1 or 2 or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do :

```
A=[1,2,3,4,5]
B=[6,7,8]

print("A: {}".format(A))
print("B: {}".format(B))
print("{}, {}".format(A, B))
```

Output:

```
A: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
B: [6, 7, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]
```

Test the code [here](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/39E22lDHSMdYx0THNJbLyTbaTMdcxyKWi6ugKDOvREPJ0UqhulZJLy2/KDexRMNRUxMm4YQi4YSQqK7VQdGiowCU/P8fAA)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using an f-string

```py
print(f"A: {A}")
print(f"B: {B}")
print(f"{A}, {B}")
```